# How to design a function with pointers with plain C

Tags: c

I am building the following function to retrieve the element name and type of a UIAutomationElement:

```c
main(){

    BSTR element_name = NULL;
    BSTR element_type = NULL;

    GetDataElement(element_name,element_type);

}

void GetDataElement(BSTR element_name, BSTR element_type){

    [code before]

    hr = IUIAutomationElement_get_CurrentName(element,&element_name);
    hr = IUIAutomationElement_get_CurrentLocalizedControlType(element,&element_type);

}
```

In both functions, get_CurrentName and get_CurrentLocalizedControlType, retrieves the element name and element type respectively as BSTR which is a pointer. I would like to receive those pointers into my main function. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
void GetDataElement(BSTR* element_name, BSTR* element_type) {
    ...
    hr = IUIAutomationElement_get_CurrentName(element, element_name);
    ...
    hr = IUIAutomationElement_get_CurrentLocalizedControlType(element, element_type);
}

int main() {
    BSTR element_name = NULL;
    BSTR element_type = NULL;

    GetDataElement(&element_name, &element_type);
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tks @goodvibration for your help. It works perfectly. I had already the pointer and I was using &. I understood well the concept now of a pointer.